# QGIS (2.14 and olders). Problems with OGC SLD Text Labels Support

Tags: qgis, labeling, sld

Could you tell me if QGIS 2.14 (and older versions) support SLD labels correctly?

I had some problems trying to incorporate some SLD files that labels specific objects in a layers.

This is my SLD code:

> ```
> <Rule>
> <Name>Index Topographic Countour</Name>
> <ogc:Filter>
>    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
>        <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
>         <ogc:Literal>60101</ogc:Literal>
>    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
> </ogc:Filter>
> <LineSymbolizer>
>    <Stroke>
>        <CssParameter name="stroke">#926239</CssParameter>
>        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.3</CssParameter>
>        <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
>    </Stroke>
>        <TextSymbolizer>
>          <Label>
>            <ogc:PropertyName>elevation</ogc:PropertyName>
>          </Label>
>          <LabelPlacement>
>            <LinePlacement />
>          </LabelPlacement>
>          <Fill>
>            <CssParameter name="fill">#926239</CssParameter>
>          </Fill>
>          <Font>
>            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
>            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
>            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
>            <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
>          </Font>
>
>        </TextSymbolizer>
>
> </LineSymbolizer>
> </Rule>
> ```

Note: I am selecting a line object using the item "id" with value 60101 and I labeled it with the item "elevation". That means in a topographic countour layer I only want to label "Index Topographic Countours" and not others. And nothing will happen with QGIS.

I also I haven't found any way to label only one specific object in  layer using common QGIS tools.

Comment: You can label one specific object in QGIS using rule-based labeling as long as each object has a unique identifier.